# Java Повернуть график

Tags: java

Необходимо повернуть график вокруг начала координат.
График без поворота:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Метод рисующий параболу
void funcPar(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    xln = (lx - l2);
    xk = 0;
    yg = 0;
    int kp = 0;
    while ((xk + hx) * ny < xln && Math.pow(xk + hx, 2) * ny < ly * ky) {

       g2d.drawLine((int) (xln - xk * ny + oxn),
                (int) (ly * ky - yg * ny + oyn),
                (int) (xln - (xk + hx) * ny + oxn),
                (int) (ly * ky - Math.pow(xk + hx, 2) * ny + oyn));
        xk = xk + hx;
        yg = (float) Math.pow(xk, 2);
        kp++;

    }
    xk = 0;
    yg = 0;
    while ((xk + hx) * ny < l2 && Math.pow(xk + hx, 2) * ny < ly * ky) {

        yg = (float) Math.pow(xk, 2);
        g2d.drawLine((int) (xln + xk * ny + oxn),
                (int) (ly * ky - yg * ny + oyn),
                (int) (xln + (xk + hx) * ny + oxn),
                (int) (ly * ky - Math.pow(xk + hx, 2) * ny) + oyn);
        xk = xk + hx;

    }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь повернуть график вставляю `g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(10));` после `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;` и получается :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Чем же вас не устраивает повернутый на 10 градусов график?

Comment: @Kromster Ну просто график съехал от начала координат:(